# Proving denseness of rationals with a nicer formula?

Tags: inequality

Is it true that if $\frac{a}{b} < \frac{c}{d}$ for all $\frac{a}{b}, \frac{c}{d} \in \mathbb{Q}$ and if $\frac{a}{b}, \frac{c}{d}$ are both simplified, that $\frac{a}{b}< \frac{a+c}{b+d} < \frac{c}{d}$ is always true?

It looks really elegant, and if true can be used to prove the denseness of the rationals in the real numbers, but I couldn't formulate a proof for it. 
I wrote a python script that checked for a, c between -60 and 59 and for b, d from 1 to 59, but I haven't found any counterexamples, however it is quite slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could prove it by cross-multiplying;

e.g., $\dfrac ab<\dfrac cd \iff ad<bc$ and

$\dfrac ab<\dfrac {a+c}{b+d} \iff ab+ad<ab+cb,$

assuming $b,d>0$.

Comment: At least for $b,d>0$, which is probably what the OP had in mind...

Comment: Yes, for b, d>0